# What is the concept (@ ) Coming before the select this code?

Tags: asp.net

What is the concept (@ ) Coming before the select this code?
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = **@**"SELECT tblstore.storname,tblproduct.pid, tblproduct.pname, tblproduct.pprice, tblproduct.publisher, tblproduct.writer FROM tblproduct INNER JOIN tblstore ON tblproduct.storeid = tblstore.storeid WHERE tblproduct.pname LIKE @ likeText;";


    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("likeText", txtName.Text);



    GridView1.EmptyDataText = "not result";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove space between `@` and `likeText` from command text

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = @"SELECT tblstore.storname,tblproduct.pid, tblproduct.pname, tblproduct.pprice, tblproduct.publisher, tblproduct.writer FROM tblproduct INNER JOIN tblstore ON tblproduct.storeid = tblstore.storeid WHERE tblproduct.pname LIKE @likeText";
```

and add parameter value like this

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("@likeText","%" + txtName.Text + "%");
```

Comment: @Zahra.. the answer is correct from sachin. If u follow as mentioned, the error will be gone.

Comment: i want type for example "bo" this code show "book" but in this code should type complete book

Comment: @ZahraJanmohammad if you entered "bo" then this code will search and return all those values which has "bo" anywhere in it. for eg. "book","tobo",textbook12"